# Qual a melhor forma de enviar post de cadastrar junto com os elementos filhos?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Estou criando uma aplicação Asp.net com o cadastro de clientes. Estou criando a página Create, que possui os campos de cadastro do próprio cliente. No entanto, o cliente pode ter vários telefones. Logo, minha ViewModel tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
public class ClienteViewModel
{
    public ClienteViewModel()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O nome é requerido")]
    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    [StringLength(80, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "{0} deve ter no mínimo 5 e no máximo 80 caracteres.")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Data de Nascimento é requerida")]
    [Display(Name = "Data de Nascimento")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
}
```

Porém, como posso enviar essa lista de telefones na Controller em uma estrutura como essa? Poderia usar Ajax com partialView, mas aí eu teria que ter o ID (o cliente cadastrado primeiro). Gostaria de saber a melhor forma pra fazer algo parecido com a tela abaixo:

```
   [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ClienteViewModel clienteViewModel)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: é um `array` de `string` tipo `public string[] Telefones {get;set;}`

Comment: Mas como passar isso, já que estão em campos diferentes? Como organizo para que envie por post (sem ajax)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De maneira simples coloque na sua classe `ClienteViewModel` um campo que vai receber a coleção de telefones citados na sua pergunta `public string[] Telefones { get; set; }`:

```
public class ClienteViewModel
{
    public ClienteViewModel()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O nome é requerido")]
    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    [StringLength(80, MinimumLength = 5")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Data de Nascimento é requerida")]
    [Display(Name = "Data de Nascimento")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }

    public string[] Telefones { get; set; }
}
```

logo após essa mudança do seu modelo reparei que foi criado dinamicamente essas caixas de textos na sua `View` e para que as informações de telefone sejam trazidas precisa seguir uma nomenclatura de `nome do campo` e `chave de índice` que cada elemento criado, exemplo:

```
<div class="form-group" id="">
  <label asp-for="Telefones" class="control-label"></label>
  <input asp-for="Telefones[0]" class="form-control" />
  <span asp-validation-for="Telefones" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="">
  <label asp-for="Telefones" class="control-label"></label>
  <input asp-for="Telefones[1]" class="form-control" />
  <span asp-validation-for="Telefones" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

ou seja, no exemplo tem o campos `Telefones[0]` e `Telefones[1]` isso significa que o nome do campo e seu índice que começa do 0 até o total de telefones que assim deseja enviar para o seu objeto da classe `ClienteViewModel`.

Então, reafirmando quando for criado os campos dinamicamente precisa seguir o nome do campo e em colchetes o número do seu índice começando do número 0.

Comment: Show de bola. Obrigado!!!! Era isso mesmo que eu queria. Tem como fazer com List<string> também?

Comment: Tem sim @ComplexityAlg ... é só colocar esse tipo no lugar do outro.